# creating multiple PNG using parallel operation

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to create 4 png using parallel operation..

the following is the Kindof psuedo code.... Basically I am trying to reduce the processing time, ie. sequentially it takes more time to create 4 png with all the plotting.. anyways I tried something like this and it doesnt work...

```
library(doSNOW)
library(foreach)
cl<- makeCluster(6, type = "SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)

foreach(i=1:4) %dopar%
{

Name <- Name <- paste(i, "dim.png", sep="_")
CairoPNG(filename = Name,  width = 900,  height = 480, pointsize = 12,  bg = "white")

# The plotting code goes here
dev.off()
}
```

My question is,  is it possible to create multiple png parallely ? or is there a better way to do ?

Amar

Answer (score 3):

The error you get:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "CairoPNG""
```

warns that your nodes (or slaves) need the `Cairo` package loaded. You can do so by running

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(Cairo))
```

before your `foreach` call, or you can add `require(Cairo)` within the `foreach` block.

For everything `snow` related, I always find this page really helpful: http://www.sfu.ca/~sblay/R/snow.html

Comment: good point, but I am using library(cairo) already, probably I missed mentioning that.. but my question is can 4 or multiple png created parallely ? and sure will look into the link you provided for snow.

Comment: `library(Cairo)` in your main script will only load the package on the master, not the nodes. Why don't you try what I suggested? Yes, it will create multiple PNGs in parallel.